# Why Soap Serializer does not support serializing Generic Types?

Tags: serialization, soapformatter

I have tried to serialize `Dictionary<string, string>` using `SoapFormatter`, but it throws an exception

> Soap Serializer does not support serializing Generic Types :
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String].

Serialization of `Dictionary<string, string>` works with BinaryFormatter.

Anyone have idea about why `SoapFormatter` does not support serializing Generic Types?

Comment: SoapFormater is being deprecated, this might be the reason for the same.

Answer (score 4):

The SoapFormatter class can only serialize objects that could have been created with .NET 1.1.

As generic types were not introduced until .NET 2.0, they cannot therefore be serialized.

If you're trying to serialize a List, then you could use an ArrayList instead or, if you're trying to serialize a generic Dictionary then you could use a Hashset.

Otherwise, I'd use the BinaryFormatter instead.